# Design a procedure to reverse a list

Tags: recursion, lisp, scheme, sicp

SICP exercise 2.18 asks the following:

> Exercise 2.18.  Define a procedure
>   reverse that takes a list as argument
>   and returns a list of the same
>   elements in reverse order:

```
(reverse (list 1 4 9 16 25))
(25 16 9 4 1)
```

I wrote this iterative function:

```
(define (reverse n)
  (define (iter a b)
    (if (null? a) b
        (iter (cdr a) (cons (car a) b))))
  (iter n null))
```

I could not think of a way to do this recursively.  Is there a better way to write this function?  Is it possible to do it recursively?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a recursive definition of reverse (named `rev`) that uses primitives (`car`/`cdr`/`cons`) and an inner definition of `snoc` (reverse `cons`):

```
(define (rev lis)
  (define (snoc elem lis)
    (if (null? lis)
        (cons elem lis)
        (cons (car lis) (snoc elem (cdr lis)))))
  (if (null? lis)
      lis
      (snoc (car lis) (rev (cdr lis)))))
```

Obviously, this definition is not meant to be efficient. =)

Answer (score 0):

Not much different from yours, and kind of sloppy with the list mechanics (id generally prefer to use `cons` over `append`)

```
> (define (rev l)
    (if (null? (cdr l))
        l
        (append (rev (cdr l)) (list (car l)))))
> (rev '(1 2 3 4))
(4 3 2 1)
```

This, on the other hand, i like

```
(define (rev l) (foldr (lambda (a b) (append b (list a))) l '()))
```

Comment: Interesting.  I didn't know about append - how is it different from cons?

Comment: gives a proper null-terminated list when both arguments are proper lists

Comment: there might be a way with just car/cons/cdr to do the same, but i played around for a while had a hard time making the list come out properly.  if you can find a way to tweak mine like that plz let me know

Comment: @jaresty: `append` is O(n) on the lengths of all the given lists except the last. `cons` is O(1).